# if statement on discount

Tags: if-statement

```
A_quantity = 10
B_quantity = 20
```

the quantity amount

```
N = float (input('please enter the quantity of package: '))
X_total = float (N*99.00)
```

the fee from input

```
Q_discount = (0.2*X_total)
W_discount = (X_total*0.3)
```

discounts from input total

```
Y_total = (X_total-Q_discount)
M_total = (X_total-W_discount)
```

the fee with the discount

```
def main ():
 if N >= A_quantity:
     print ('the total cost is $', \
            format (Y_total, ',.2f'))
 else:
     if N >= B_ quantity:
         print ('the total cost is $', \
                format (M_total, ',.2f'))

main ()
```

the results should be 10 packages for $792.00

and 20 packages for $1,380.00

yet the second statement gets the 20% discount also which total to $1549.00, when it should get only 30% discount

Comment: You might want consider tagging this with a specific programming language.

Comment: sry but this for fun OMG ITS CHRIS COOPER LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which language it is, but it's an algorithm problem : you should first try for the highest value cause the way it is designed now, if N = 30 , you will always enter the "if" , never the "else" , and if N=5 , you will enter the "else" , but the the if inside it...

let me try although I don't know the language:

```
def main ():
 if N >= B_quantity:
 print ('the total cost is $', \
        format (M_total, ',.2f'))
 else:
 if N >= A_quantity:
     print ('the total cost is $', \
            format (Y_total, ',.2f'))

main ()
```

Answer (score 0):

take the value of the product divided by 100 and multiplied by the discount

and then get this result and the value of the product subitrair

```
var SomaPercent = ValorUnit/100 * descont;

var result_fim = ValorUnit-SomaPercent;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the **if** condition to

> if N >= A_quantity && N < B_quantity ...
>
> if N >= B_quantity
>
> ..